# Post-merge PoA private network with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, geth-clique, the-merge

Crossposting this from r/ethdev as I have the feeling I have a better chance for an answer here.

> Hi, I have been playing around with ethereum private networks for a
> couple months, deploying them in my local machine with docker compose,
> mostly to practise with solidity and with the ethernaut challenges.
> Until now I have had only chains that are pre-merge, mostly because
> that is how the geth docs tell you to create them, and always using
> PoA (via clique) for simplicity.
>
> Past week, I thought to make this setup post-merge from the genesis,
> and to my surprise, I haven't been able to use clique when I set them
> to be post-merge. I always get the message:
>
> "Consensus: Beacon (proof-of-stake), merged from Clique
> (proof-of-authority)"
>
> And then the nodes just wait for the beacon network to be available,
> and it never starts to process blocks.
>
> What am I missing here?  Is it not possible to use clique in the
> post-merge world? Or do I need, somehow, a beacon node running clique?
>
> I have been looking into the geth source code, and can't find a
> codepath that would use clique if the genesis is configured for post
> merge...
>
> Thanks in advance, hope this is not a silly noob question

Comment: Could you specify the exact version of Geth you used with the commit number and the branch? Perhaps I can clone the repo, do the test myself and let you know what is going on?

Comment: @Deepal version is:
`1.12.0-stable-e501b3b0`  
Is the binary from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads
  
For reference the significant part of the genesis block:
`"londonBlock": 0, "mergeForkBlock": 0, "mergeNetsplitBlock": 0, "terminalTotalDifficulty":0, "terminalTotalDifficultyPassed":true, "clique": { "period": 5, "epoch": 30000 }`
  
In any case I have run into some twits where it is mentioned that clique will soon be removed from geth, so I wouldn't be surprised if this just does not work